# Excel column autofill (autoincrement with formula)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

500 employees will have 3 hours of work each day (for sample made weekday image sample). so i tried with auto increment for B2 cell "=sum(A2+3)".
problem arise when i try to enter Absent data or the cell is cleared the data starts from 3 like in E4 or like in E5. need to Enter AA for absent data for that day.

Comment: I have no idea how you are going to use a formula, when your are manually entering AA or Absent, isn't the formula overrides it,

Comment: `=MAX($A2:A2)+3` pulled to the right

Comment: Or more dynamic, can be pasted any row column after column 2: `=MAX(INDEX(1:1048576,ROW(),2):INDEX(1:1048576,ROW(),COLUMN()-1))+3`

Comment: @P.b but could you tell me one thing which i am not able to understand if OP is entering any value like Absent in any cell how is it going to work. I am asking because I am not able to understand what OP is asking

Comment: Yes, as soon as a value is entered, the formula is gone, but the next cell will still calculate correctly (or you can paste the formula anywhere/any time. But I understand your question. That's why I answered in the comments instead of as answer. It's only a way to get there, but not a real solution. That would require VBA, but I doubt there really is the need.

Comment: @P.b yes i agree with you, i was anticipating that only, this query actually needs VBA solution, However your formula is very practical solution,

Answer (score 1):

So base the calculation on col A only and multiply the 3 by the column number less 1:

```
=$A2+(3*(col()-1))
```

as the column position will multiply by 1, 2 or 3 etc similar to the progression you expected from your method.